# React-big-calendar week/day view timestamp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-big-calendar

I want to display just the title in week/day view like in the months but the library inserts it by itself. How to get reed of "4:54 PM - 7:54: at the head of the cell?

Answer (score 0):

```
formats: {formats.eventTimeRangeFormat: () => ''}
```